# How to replace by localhost link ? Android

Tags: android, http, localhost

I am parsing an xml file.
One of the method is below :

```
public static String getXML(){   
        String line = null;

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://p-xr.com/xml/");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        }

        return line;

}
```

Here, I want to replace

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://p-xr.com/xml/");
```

by

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/myfile.xml");
```

As i can browse `http://127.0.0.1/myfile.xml` in my browser.
But when i write this address to above code it doenst work.
why ?
My project requires http method to access xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 10.0.2.2 in this case, check out [Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking).

Comment: It works fine.
But results are display for very short time and force close error appear.
But when i replace `http://10.0.2.2/myfile.xml` by `http://p-xr.com/xml/` no any force close appear.
Thanx !

Comment: @captainpirate, glad to hear it helps:)

Answer (score 2):

In emulator the localhost is the emulator itself not your system which runs the emulator. So it will not work.

Use 10.0.2.2 instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the emulator there are some specially defined address aliases used to access networks outside of the emulator itself.

To access localhost on the system running the emulator (ie. the host system), use `10.0.2.2`

Reference here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Answer (score 1):

If you're want to do this with an Android device:

You can find out the IP address of your computer by using `ifconfig` on Mac or Linux or `ipconfig` on Windows.

Then you can replace p-xr.com / 127.0.0.1 with that IP address.

You'll need to make sure that you don't have a firewall set up on your computer and if so, you'll have to allow access to your Android device in order to contact your local HTTP server.

Comment: Thanx u all guys for the reply.
It works gr8, i have headache over this for 2 days.